# Bootstrap using rsample package is much slower than using boot package

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I found that using the `boot` package like this

```
library(boot)

calculate_mean_1 <- function(.data, i){
  mean(.data$mpg[i])
}

system.time(
  samples_1 <- boot(mtcars, statistic = calculate_mean_1, R=10000)$t
)
```

I can create bootstrap samples more than 10 times faster than using the `rsample`package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

calculate_mean_2 <- function(.data) {
  mean(analysis(.data)$mpg)
}

system.time(
  samples_2 <- bootstraps(mtcars, times = 10000) %>% 
    mutate(m = map_dbl(splits, calculate_mean_2))
)
```

I wonder whether I am using `rsample` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing it right. I assume that the difference is that `rsample` uses lists rather than a standard vector. The advantage of `rsample` is that you can have multiple statistics calculated in the same run, so you might gain some time if you are doing that (and make the code easier to read).

Comment: You can also calculate multiple statistics using `boot()` as well by having the function you bootstrap return a vector of values. I think the real benefit may be in post-processing the results.  It is easier to generate bootstrapped confidence intervals for all parameters using the `int_*` functions in the tidy framework.

Answer (score 0):

To close the gap in performance, consider drawing bootstrap samples from a subset of the dataframe.

```
system.time(
  samples_3 <- bootstraps(mtcars %>% dplyr::select(mpg), times = 10000) %>% 
    mutate(m = map_dbl(splits, calculate_mean_2))
)
```